# Get composed frames from Qt WaylandOutput

Tags: qt, output, streaming, wayland, off-screen

I'm starting to look into the Qt WaylandCompositor and I am wondering if it is possible to get access to the composed frame of a WaylandOutput, preferably rendered off-screen. So that I can implement something similar than the Weston remoting plugin for streaming the composed scene to other devices.

Looking into the topic, I found the `QWaylandView` that offers access to a `QWaylandBufferRef`, but I guess this can be only used for a surface that is input to the composer... Is there something similar for the `QWaylandOutput`?

About the off-screen rendering, I found `QOffscreenSurface`, but I found no way so far on how to tell the output to use the `OffscreenSurface` instead of the `window` binding.

Does anyone have ideas on how to approach this?

Any help is deeply appreciated.